# Give a custom position to google maps map type control style object? (html, css, google-maps, asp.net)

Tags: html, css, asp.net, google-maps

As you know here are the position options for the google maps - map type control style object:

[image]

I set it 'LEFT_BOTTOM'

```
position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
```

but

i would like to put this object little bit top like in the image below:

[image]

Let's assume that 20px top. Is there any way to custom this position? (HTML, CSS, ASP.NET)

Comment: What element are you trying to insert there and how? Please provide your code.

Comment: Map type, Select object like a 'roadmap', 'hybrid', 'terrain', 'satellite' @MrUpsidown

Comment: I still don't see your code. If you need full control on the appearance, styling or placement of a control, hide it and create your own [custom control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom). By simply adding some bottom margin to your custom element, you can control where it will appear.

Comment: I will examine it and then i will write result in here. But i wonder if there is more easy way to do it. I am gonna share my whole code after i simplify it. Thanks a lot

Comment: There is no documented method for styling these default controls other than changing their position (as you know already) or changing their aspect (for some controls) also with some ready-to-use customizations (see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/control#MapTypeControlStyle for the map style button). Don't try to use CSS to override the controls positions as this is undocumented. Go back to by comment above... if you need full control -> Custom controls.